# Linux ncurses overwriting border created by box()

Tags: c++, linux, border, ncurses

When I execute this code, the left side of the border I've created is being overwritten in the top-right box. The problem seems to be localized to this area, even though the code seems identical. How can I prevent this from overwriting my border?
I'm compiling with g++ -lncurses and running in an Ubuntu terminal

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h> 
#define WINDOWY 24
#define WINDOWX 80
#define ROW1 3
#define RROW1 1
#define COL1 2
#define COL2 23
#define COL3 33 
#define COL4 38
#define MEMORYROW 9
#define MEMORYCOL 1
#define COMMANDROW 1
#define COMMANDCOL 41


int closeUp(void);
void printMockup(void);
void drawBorders(void);
WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx);

int main()
{
    char input = ' ';
    int row,col;    

    //initialize ncurses stuff
    initscr();      
    cbreak();
    curs_set(0);

    //check window is right size
    getmaxyx(stdscr,row,col);
    if (row < WINDOWY || col < WINDOWX)
    {
        printw("You need to increase the terminal size to at least 24 x 70");
        return closeUp();
    }

    //draw border
    drawBorders();

    //draw UI
    printMockup();

    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}



int closeUp(void)
{
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}



void printMockup(void)
{
    mvprintw(1, 2, "6808 Emulator");
    mvprintw(ROW1, COL1, "Accumulator:");
    mvprintw(ROW1, COL2, "0x00");
    mvprintw(ROW1+1, COL1, "Program Counter:");
    mvprintw(ROW1+1, COL2, "0x0000");
    mvprintw(ROW1+2, COL1, "Stack Pointer:");
    mvprintw(ROW1+2, COL2, "0x0000");
    mvprintw(ROW1+3, COL1, "Index Register Low:");
    mvprintw(ROW1+3, COL2, "0x00");
    mvprintw(ROW1+4, COL1, "Index Register High:");
    mvprintw(ROW1+4, COL2, "0x00");

    mvprintw(RROW1, COL3, "PC:");
    mvprintw(RROW1, COL4, "0");
    mvprintw(RROW1+1, COL3, "C:");
    mvprintw(RROW1+1, COL4, "0");
    mvprintw(RROW1+2, COL3, "Z:");
    mvprintw(RROW1+2, COL4, "0");
    mvprintw(RROW1+3, COL3, "N:");
    mvprintw(RROW1+3, COL4, "0");
    mvprintw(RROW1+4, COL3, "I:");
    mvprintw(RROW1+4, COL4, "0");
    mvprintw(RROW1+5, COL3, "H:");
    mvprintw(RROW1+5, COL4, "0");
    mvprintw(RROW1+6, COL3, "V:");
    mvprintw(RROW1+6, COL4, "0");

    mvprintw(COMMANDROW+1, COMMANDCOL+11, "r - Run");
    mvprintw(COMMANDROW+2, COMMANDCOL+11, "s - Step");
    mvprintw(COMMANDROW+3, COMMANDCOL+11, "a - Auto-step");
    mvprintw(COMMANDROW+4, COMMANDCOL+11, "x - Reset");
    mvprintw(COMMANDROW+5, COMMANDCOL+11, "m - Main menu");

    mvprintw(MEMORYROW+1, MEMORYCOL+1, "PC:");
    mvprintw(MEMORYROW+1, MEMORYCOL+1, "0");

}



WINDOW *create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx)
{   
    WINDOW *local_win;

    local_win = newwin(height, width, starty, startx);
    //wborder(local_win, '|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+');
    box(local_win, 0 , 0);
    wrefresh(local_win);

    return local_win;
}



void drawBorders(void)
{
    refresh();
    create_newwin(WINDOWY, WINDOWX, 0, 0);
    create_newwin(WINDOWY-(WINDOWY-MEMORYROW-1)-2, WINDOWX-COMMANDCOL-1, COMMANDROW, COMMANDCOL);
    create_newwin(WINDOWY-MEMORYROW-1, WINDOWX-MEMORYCOL-1, MEMORYROW, MEMORYCOL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically print into a window, and refresh it. For this particular problem, we can fix it by just focusing on your "command window". Given the structure of your code, create a global variable to hold the command window pointer.

```
WINDOW *command_window;
```

Then, initialize it from your `drawBorders()` function.

```
command_window = create_newwin(WINDOWY-(WINDOWY-MEMORYROW-1)-2,
                               WINDOWX-COMMANDCOL-1,
                               COMMANDROW, COMMANDCOL);
```

Modify the code that prints the commands into the primary window to print it into the `command_window` instead. And then, refresh the `command_window`.

```
mvwprintw(command_window, 1, 11, "r - Run");
mvwprintw(command_window, 2, 11, "s - Step");
mvwprintw(command_window, 3, 11, "a - Auto-step");
mvwprintw(command_window, 4, 11, "x - Reset");
mvwprintw(command_window, 5, 11, "m - Main menu");
wrefresh(command_window);
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much! This solution of refreshing only the necessary windows is much better too.